# SharePoint 2010 Ampersand in Search Query String

Tags: document-library, search-results, metadata

Our XSL is set up so that when search results come up a user can click on an icon to go to that exact document in our library. The problem is when a document has an ampersand (&) in the metadata column "Title" and the icon is clicked the document isn't found in the library. Just as a side note the document does show up in the search results. A sample of the icon's URL is below.

If I replace the **ampersand (&)** in the URL with **%26** the document is found in the library.

***My question**: What can I do to the URL to replace the ampersand (&) with "%26" for the Title metadata column only (This is my preferred method)?*  Or will I have to go through the 300+ documents with ampersand (&) in the titles and replace with the word "**and**" instead (help with a PowerShell command?).

***This is what the URL of the icon used to go to the document in the library looks like before I reaplace the & with %26***

http://myportal.domain.com/My%20Library/Forms/AllItems.aspx?InitialTabId=Ribbon.Document&VisibilityContext=WSSTabPersistence&View={FF43BG1F-4F18-4040-9C52-G49G1GGE9F2Q}&FilterField1=Title&FilterValue1=Care Management Solution Features & Benefits video

Answer (score 1):

Store the URL as a variable in XSL and then show the output with disabling output escaping.

```
<xsl:variable name="test" select="http://www.mysite.com/mypage.aspx?param1=1&amp;param2=2" />

<xsl:value-of select="$test" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
```

Comment: I'm not that familiar with XSL is this correct? `<xsl:variable name="titleamp" select="http://myportal.domain.com/My%20Library/Forms/AllItems.aspx?InitialTabId=Ribbon.Document&VisibilityContext=WSSTabPersistence&View={FF43BG1F-4F18-4040-9C52-G49G1GGE9F2Q}&FilterField1=Title&FilterValue1=Care Management Solution Features & Benefits video " /> <xsl:value-of select="$test" disable-output-escaping="yes" />` Will adding this variable do anything to the ampersands (&) in all of the other places in my sample?

Comment: This should do the trick, maybe you can encounter some problems with the space ( '  ' ). But you should first try this one. Good luck

Comment: Thank you very much BenCes.  I will give this a try once I set up a test environment.

Comment: Don't forget to mark this as an answer

Comment: Did this work out for you? Mark this as an answer please.